# Print out seconds on screen by replacing them without clear screen

Tags: c, time, printf, sleep, seconds

I've tried but still dont know yet. I want to print out the result like this: seconds(10) -> seconds(9) -> ... -> seconds(1) by replacing each integer in every second without system("cls").

[sample program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOGsZ.png)

Comment: `printf("10"); sleep(1); printf("\b\b 9"); sleep(1); printf("\b8"); ...` or try [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: **Please don't post pictures of text**. Post text as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

You could print `\r` to return the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec st = {.tv_sec = 1, .tv_nsec = 0};

    for(int i = 10; i>=0; --i) {
        printf("%2d\r", i);    // \r to return to the beginning of the line
        fflush(stdout);        // flush to ensure it's actually printed

        thrd_sleep(&st, NULL); // sleep a second
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stayerr You're welcome! Since you are new here, you may want to read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)